# Why is my bootstrap (3) grid not responsive?

Tags: css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm probably missing something silly here, but I cannot figure out why my bootstrap grid is not responsive. The item data is being passed through by Node and works perfectly - I get a grid of item thumbnails and their captions in rows of 4. But when I minimise the page, the images just get smaller ie they stay in rows of 4. With the  `col-sm-6` it should surely break into rows of 2 items and eventually 1 item as I reduce the screen width. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <div class="row text-center" style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap">
        <% items.forEach(function(item){ %>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="<%= item.image %>">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4><%= item.name %> </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% }); %>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after try it's actually work well:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row text-center" style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>test </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>test </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>test </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>test </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The code seems to be correct. For whatever reason it isn't working in google chrome but works in other browsers. Bizarre!

Comment: @bobby_belfast I tried on google chrome with JsFiddle and work well. Can you see the downloaded css file from bootstrap in your browser console ? If yes please `validate` this answer thanks :)

Comment: @bobby_belfast Can you please `upvote` and `validate` my answer please ? ;)

Comment: @bobby_belfast Thanks for the `validation` ;) Can you please `upvote` my question too ?